# DotNetNuke GetCurrentUserInfo working for Superusers but not Regular ones

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

I have a web service in which I'm returning some user details. I had to look at the source of `UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo()` and copy it over to my own stuff with a slight modification to get around the webservice/auth issues in DNN. When I am signed in as the main superuser, I can populate the `UserInfo` object properly and all my data makes it back. When I am signed in as a regular user, I get an empty object.

To test, in some actual module code, I tried the "real" `UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo()` and just grabbed a string to insert into the page directly, and it *did* work for all user types.

My webservice is working successfully on my local DNN install for all user types. When I installed on a shared-dev environment, I started getting this strange behavior. Any ideas? I'm hoping it's just something how I installed in the module in shared dev, but I'm not seeing anywhere I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running on a child portal in your shared environment?  You may need to add `portalId` to the querystring, so that DNN knows which portal you're making the request for (which is why it works with a superuser, since they have an account already, even if the portal is identified incorrectly).

Have you considered using the [DNN Services Framework](http://bit.ly/DNN-Services) to implement your service, instead of having to work around these issue when using your own service?

Comment: That was it. I *was* including the PortalID, but it was incorrectly using 0 (my sub-site should've been 11). I tried hard-coding it for testing and it worked with 11. Now I need to figure out my problem with the Portal ID coming back wrong...Thanks for the services link, too!